# Game - Convert pitch and yaw to XY

Tags: java

I'm trying to display an image on a point on the screen.

I have the pitch and the yaw of the current point. All I need is to convert these values to a 2 coord points.

Here is what I've done so far:

```
double tmp_yaw = yaw - myPlayer_yaw;
double tmp_pitch = pitch - myPlayer_pitch;

if (tmp_yaw < -180D) tmp_yaw += 360D;
if (tmp_yaw > 180D) tmp_yaw -= 360D;

// X Y screen coords
int x = (tmp_yaw / 180) * (screen_width / 2);
int y = (tmp_pitch / 90) * (screen_height / 2);
```

At first glance, this code looks easy but I don't know why I doesn't display the point where it is expected.

Variables `yaw` and `pitch` are here the rotation to the point in 3D.

Variables `myPlayer_yaw` and `myPlayer_pitch` stand for where the player is looking at any moment.

Did I do something wrong?

[image]

I want to get those kind of results:

- I'm looking a player => Returns (height/2, width/2)
- The player is behind me => Returns (height, width/2)
- The player is on my left => Returns (height/2, 0)
- The player is on my right => Returns (height/2, width)
- The player is just above me => Returns (0, width/2)

Comment: Pitch and yaw are measurements of angle.  How do intend to map an angle to a screen position?

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I want

Comment: Point is at the bottom when the yaw is 180, etc...

Comment: That's not very clear.  You're saying you simply want (ignoring scaling factor and offset), `x = pitch`, `y = yaw`?

Comment: Where is the code that displays the points?

Comment: Not exactly, I want to display a line from the center of the screen to a given point. This point is obtained by `yaw` and `pitch`. These values are the yaw and pitch it would be if the player was looking at the point.

Comment: That's still completely unclear.  Please add some concrete examples to your question.  For example, where should the following points be mapped to: (-180,0), (0,0), (0,180), (90,45)?

Comment: (-180, 0) => bottom_vertical and center_horizontal, (0, 0) => center, (0, 90) => top_vertical and center_horizontal, (90, 45) => top left corner

Comment: That doesn't make any sense at all.

Comment: Can't we just say that more information needs to be put into the question?

Comment: Imagine that I'm a player in the game. I want to display a line to another player, like a tracer. I want this line starts in the center of my screen (ie. where i am aiming) and ends where the player is. I've tried to do that with the OpenGL library (gluProject) but it doesn't deal with the rotation.

Comment: @Vodemki: But what do pitch and yaw have to do with where the other player is?

Comment: Well I made a bit of maths to retreive the yaw and pitch I would need to aim the player

Comment: @Vodemki: I'm sorry, but you just aren't explaining this sufficiently for anyone to understand what you want to do.  Perhaps draw a diagram (with concrete examples of coordinates), and put that in your question.

Comment: I'm sorry that's hard to explain, even for me. Let me a sec for the scheme.

Comment: Here it is: http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg109/scaled.php?server=109&filename=scheme.png&res=landing

Left column is what I see in my 3D view. Right column is where the player is (coord). The red line is what I want.

Comment: I want to convert the pitch/yaw difference (between your current pitch/yaw and the pitch/yaw looking at the player) to an on screen X Y coordinate/point.

Comment: I've edited your question to include the image.  But please update the image to show some *concrete* examples of pitch/yaw values.  Without that, it's impossible to suggest what the relevant code should be.

Comment: Well, pitch is between -90 to 90 and equals 0 when perfectly is the center. Yaw is between -360 and 360.

Comment: That doesn't agree with what you wrote earlier...

Comment: Why? -360 = 0 and +360 = 0. Back is 180 or -180.

Comment: For instance, "(90,45) is top-left corner".

Comment: What's the problem? (90, 45) means he is a bit highter and on my left.

Comment: Honestly, I think you should start this question from scratch, because what's here is far too confused.  Just give some real examples of: (1) inputs, (2) expected outputs, (3) actual outputs.

Comment: Well, if I put my aim on the player, I want it to returns me (0, 0). If the player is just behind me, it should return (-180, 0) or (180, 0). If the player is on my left, it should return (-90, 0). On my right (90, 0). What I have actually, is a weird result such as (-50, 90) when I look the player. (yaw, pitch)

Comment: Please edit your question to include *specific* input values and output values.

Comment: so (0, 0) means center of the screen. (-180, 0) means (height, width/2). (90, 0) means (height/2, 0) and (90, 0) means (height/2, width)

Comment: Having read all of this, I now have a question. Why are these "angles" so important?

Comment: No, I mean specific *numeric* input values.  What are the values of `pitch` and `yaw` that you input, and what are the values of `x` and `y` that you get out, and what are the values that you want?

Comment: What the question is really asking, is how do I make gluProject work so that it includes my camera position and rotation. The rotation should be included in your projection matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it using `vertex3D`

Here is the code:

```
public void drawLine(Vector3 origin, Vector3 destination, int color)
{
    GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    GL11.glLineWidth(3.0F);
    GL11.glDisable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    GL11.glDepthMask(false);
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_LINES);

    float red = (float)((color & 0xFF0000) >> 16);
    float green = (float)((color & 0x00FF00) >> 8);
    float blue = (float)(color & 0x0000FF);
    GL11.glColor3f(red, green, blue);

    double diffX = destination.x() - origin.x() + 0.05D;
    double diffY = destination.y() - origin.y() - 1.35D;
    double diffZ = destination.z() - origin.z() - 0.05D;

    GL11.glVertex3d(0.0D, 0.0D, 0.0D);
    GL11.glVertex3d( -diffX, -diffY, -diffZ);

    GL11.glEnd();
    GL11.glDepthMask(true);
    GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
}
```

You can use it like that:

```
Vector3 vOrg = new Vector3(x, y, z);
Vector3 vDest = new Vector3(cameraX, cameraY, cameraZ);
drawLine(vOrg, vDest, 0xFF0000); // Will display a red line (RGB format)
```

I hope this will help someone.